# Does the Steam version of Wonderful Everyday VN have upscaled CG?

Tags: visual-novel-production, wonderful-everyday

I'd like to buy *[Wonderful Everyday](http://store.steampowered.com/app/658620/Wonderful_Everyday_Down_the_RabbitHole/)* VN. I know that this VN is an old one. The CG was made around 2000-2010 in 480p.

Does the Steam version of this VN have the CG upscaled from 480p to 720p? Or do  they still use the 480p CG like the Japanese version?

I mean, I saw the CG on the internet, the VN still have the black bar for both side like it was made around 2000, is this same with the Steam version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, the CG images have been upscaled to 1280x960.**

Quoting the [official Kickstarter page](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/frontwing/a-wonderful-welcome-for-visual-novel-wonderful-eve/description),

> Furthermore, the English release has been newly upscaled to 1280x960 from the original 4:3 assets, by the same team at KeroQ that worked on the original Japanese release, to ensure maximum faithfulness to the intended product.

[Operation Rainfall](https://operationrainfall.com/2017/08/30/frontwings-wonderful-everyday-steam/) also confirmed it,

> All of the CG images have been increased to 1280 x 960 resolution [...]

Regarding the black bar, it's because the CG's aspect ratio is still in 4:3 (16:12) while most screens are in 16:9 or 16:10 nowadays. Since the aspect ratio is not the same, the CG won't fit the whole screen and thus [letterboxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_(filming)) is used.